# Trigger custom geoprocessing tool outside ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, trigger

I have created a model in a custom toolbox with ModelBuilder in ArcMap 10.1.

Is it possible to trigger the model outside ModelBuilder and ArcMap?

For example, use a Python script to trigger the model to operate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can use `ImportToolbox` to do the job ([docs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/ImportToolbox/018v0000005z000000/)):

```
import arcpy
arcpy.ImportToolbox('C:/tools/my_toolbox.tbx')
arcpy.MyModel_MyToolbox()
```

Note that the 'MyToolbox' part in the third line comes from the toolbox `Alias` you set, and `MyModel` should match the name of the model or function. This should work equivalently for Script tools, ModelBuilder models, and Python Toolbox tools.